# Java stream reduce function. Associativity of accumulator

Tags: java

Below is the Oracle Java 13 documentation:

> U reduce​(U identity,
> BiFunction accumulator,
> BinaryOperator combiner)
> Parameters:
> identity - the identity value for the combiner function
> accumulator - an associative, non-interfering, stateless function for incorporating an additional element into a result
> combiner - an associative, non-interfering, stateless function for combining two values, which must be compatible with the accumulator function

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(U,java.util.function.BiFunction,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)

First, I know that an operator's associativity means (a op b) op c == a op (b op c).
Wikipedia says that associative property is a property of some binary operations.
Binary operation means f: S × S → S.

Here is my question: how could an accumulator be associative if the accumulator function's domain is not S x S but S x T?
 For example,

```
    int length = asList("str1", "str2").stream()  
        .reduce(0, (accumulatedInt, str ) -> accumulatedInt + str.length(), 
                    (accumulatedInt, accumulatedInt2) -> accumulatedInt + accumulatedInt2);
```

In this case, the accumulator is `(accumulatedInt, str ) -> accumulatedInt + str.length()` and it's not associative. It takes two different type of parameters. How could it be (a op b) op c == a op (b op c). What does java documentation mean by "accumulator must be associative"?

Comment: No, that is not the combiner. It is the accumulator.

Comment: Sorry I meant an accumulator. I understand that a combiner must be associative. I edited.

Comment: Accumulator from Javadoc is defined as:

   `BiFunction<U, ? super T, U> accumulator`
`<? super T>` accepts either Parent or Grandparent which is integer value as your identity `U` is already defined as Integer so the later part is also inferred as integer.

Comment: @Vishwa the accumulator in the example code takes an int and a string, then returns an int. So it's S X T → S, isn't it?

Comment: You're right, [*associative*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Associativity) makes no sense for the *accumulator*, since the 2 inputs are not of the same type. You should file a bug report to get the javadoc fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of this `reduce` method, the associativity of the `accumulator` can be expressed in terms of the `accumulator` and the `combiner` functions (in addition to the `identity` value).

For example, suppose your `Stream` has elements t1, t2 and t3.

You can add t1 and t2 to an intermediate result, and then add t3 to that result - this would be the equivalent of `(t1 op t2) op t3`.

Or you can add t2 and t3 to an intermediate result, and then add t1 to that result - this would be the equivalent of `t1 op (t2 op t3)`.

Associativity means that the final result must be the same in both cases.

To write this is terms of the accumulator and combiner functions, it will look like this (I'm not writing the explicit method calls, since that would be less readable in my opinion):

```
((identity <accumulator> t1) <accumulator> t2) <accumulator> t3 ==
(identity <accumulator> t1) <combiner> ((identity <accumulator> t2) <accumulator> t3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is not what I want to know. If I can interpret the word "associativity" flexibly I agree that in this case it involves ```combiner``` and ```accumulator```. But strictly, I can't find any definition of associativity except "associative property is a property of some binary operations". Even oracle docs explains associativity only for that case. And flexible, not-definition-based reasoning is not permitted in Programming.